# What is the purpose of ath10k/pre-cal-pci and ath10k/cal-pci?

Tags: debian, firmware

I'm running Debian 9 including non-free firmware, in order to get my wifi to work. I do apparently have the necessary firmware as my wifi works, but I do still get the following output after running dmesg:

```
[    4.225315] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[    4.225317] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.225329] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[    4.225330] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
```

I can't seem to find the files pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin or cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin anywhere. As my wifi seems to work flawlessly without them, what is the purpose of these firmware files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are pre-calibration and calibration files; they are [optional](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/core.c#n1005), and as you’ve noticed, the device can work fine without them. Calibration data can be obtained in a variety of ways (from EEPROM in the device, from files on disk, from device tree information). I get the impression the “firmware” files are intended for very specific configurations (where the PCI *location* would be fixed); so basically their purpose appears to be to provide a means for systems integrators to provide their own calibration data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately without these optional pre-calibration files I get very poor 2g performance:

`iperf3 -c 192.168.11.1`:

```
Connecting to host 192.168.11.1, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.11.177 port 38740 connected to 192.168.11.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.54 MBytes  12.9 Mbits/sec    0   65.0 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.10 MBytes  9.24 Mbits/sec    0   72.1 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.16 MBytes  9.75 Mbits/sec    0   74.9 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.33 MBytes  11.1 Mbits/sec    0   83.4 KBytes
```

`lsusb`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Comment: I couldn't find these files either. But more information on pre-calibration files can be found here: https://usermanual.wiki/Pdf/80Y03061WIRELESSCONNECTIVITYTESTSUSERGUIDE.338972747/help