# PC refuses to respond after lid down for a few hours

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, systemd-networkd

The pc doesn't go to sleep because I have that disabled and works with the lid down, but after some time the system drops off the network and physically accessing the device results in the screen being off (not on with no display, but off) the keyboard lighting still works and press caps turns on or off the light but the display doesn't power on not does it connect to the network

I have configured loginctl to ignore lidswitch which works for a few hours before the PC drops from the wifi network and on physically accessing it refuses to turn on, and the PC reconnects to wifi on disconnecting the PC drops the wifi connection within minutes.

I have looked in the dmesg and search for mentions of my wifi drivers `ath10k` which shows nothing out of the ordinary

```
[   10.421971] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   10.702774] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin (-2)
[   10.702813] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin (-2)
[   10.702850] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin (-2)
[   10.702872] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin (-2)
[   10.706800] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
[   10.706824] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 target 0x05020000 chip_id 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035
[   10.706830] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   10.707653] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 42e41877
[   10.782139] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
[   10.782437] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[   13.101787] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.56 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   14.340785] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

The failed to load lines are [harmless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405015/586482)
Here is the wifi card

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

I am using systemd-networkd for managing my connections because OpenMediaVault ships with it, I am on the latest debian 12 bookwork stable release.

Output of `inxi -Fzaa`

```
System:
Kernel: 6.1.0-16-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.0
parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-16-amd64
root=UUID=8e612ff6-1299-49b8-963e-fac36e627625 ro quiet
rd.luks.uuid=3f9c700c-27cb-4d44-af3c-0d6ba0d21e0f loglevel=3 radeon.cik_support=0
amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1
Console: pty pts/0 Distro: openmediavault 7.0-19 (Sandworm) base: Debian GNU/Linux 12
(bookworm)
Machine:
Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80TJ v: Lenovo ideapad 110-15ACL
serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo ideapad 110-15ACL
serial: <superuser required>
Mobo: LENOVO model: Nano 5A8 v: SDK0J40679 WIN serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Lenovo
v: 1QCN32WW date: 08/18/2016
Battery:
ID-1: BATT charge: 0 Wh (0.0%) condition: 1.6/23.8 Wh (6.7%) volts: 7.2 min: 10.8
model: LENOVO LCFC type: Unknown serial: <filter> status: not charging
CPU:
Info: model: AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Puma level: v2
built: 2014-15 process: GF 28nm family: 0x16 (22) model-id: 0x30 (48) stepping: 1
microcode: 0x7030105
Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 4 smt: <unsupported> cache: L1: 256 KiB desc: d-4x32 KiB; i-4x32 KiB
L2: 2 MiB desc: 1x2 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 998 min/max: 1000/2200 boost: enabled scaling: driver: acpi-cpufreq
governor: conservative cores: 1: 998 2: 998 3: 998 4: 998 bogomips: 17567
Flags: avx ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Vulnerabilities:
Type: gather_data_sampling status: Not affected
Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
Type: l1tf status: Not affected
Type: mds status: Not affected
Type: meltdown status: Not affected
Type: mmio_stale_data status: Not affected
Type: retbleed mitigation: untrained return thunk; SMT disabled
Type: spec_rstack_overflow status: Not affected
Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Retpolines, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: Not
affected
Type: srbds status: Not affected
Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
Device-1: AMD Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel
alternate: radeon arch: GCN-2 code: Sea Islands process: GF/TSMC 16-28nm built: 2013-17 ports:
active: eDP-1 empty: HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:01.0 chip-ID: 1002:9851 class-ID: 0300
Device-2: AMD Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 M430 Radeon 520 Mobile]
vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel alternate: radeon arch: GCN-1 code: Southern Islands
process: TSMC 28nm built: 2011-20 pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 2 link-max: gen: 3
speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:6660 class-ID: 0380 temp: 41.0 C
Device-3: IMC Networks EasyCamera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 2-1.2:4
chip-ID: 13d3:a745 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 110x28
Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: ChiMei InnoLux 0x15dc built: 2015 res: 1366x768 dpi: 101 gamma: 1.2
size: 344x193mm (13.54x7.6") diag: 394mm (15.5") ratio: 16:9 modes: max: 1366x768 min: 640x480
API: N/A Message: No display API data available in console. Headless machine?
Audio:
Device-1: AMD Kabini HDMI/DP Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
bus-ID: 00:01.1 chip-ID: 1002:9840 class-ID: 0403
Device-2: AMD FCH Azalia vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.2
chip-ID: 1022:780d class-ID: 0403
API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-16-amd64 status: kernel-api tools: N/A
Network:
Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo
driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 02:00.0
chip-ID: 168c:0042 class-ID: 0280
IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel
pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 1000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8136
class-ID: 0200
IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
IF-ID-1: br-2843d63134e5 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter>
IF-ID-2: docker0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter>
IF-ID-3: tailscale0 state: unknown speed: -1 duplex: full mac: N/A
IF-ID-4: veth0b5fec8 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
IF-ID-5: veth11e2b4f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
IF-ID-6: veth31582f8 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 2-1.1:3 chip-ID: 0cf3:e360
class-ID: e001
Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down bt-service: not found rfk-block: hardware: no
software: yes address: see --recommends
Drives:
Local Storage: total: 2.04 TiB used: 781.11 GiB (37.4%)
SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required.
ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Western Digital model: WDS240G2G0A-00JH30 size: 223.58 GiB
block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 0000
temp: 41 C scheme: GPT
ID-2: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 type: USB vendor: Seagate model: BUP Slim RD size: 931.51 GiB
block-size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B type: N/A serial: <filter> rev: 0302
ID-3: /dev/sdc maj-min: 8:32 type: USB vendor: Seagate model: BUP Slim WH size: 931.51 GiB
block-size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B type: N/A serial: <filter> rev: 0304
Partition:
ID-1: / raw-size: 37.93 GiB size: 37.04 GiB (97.65%) used: 30.31 GiB (81.8%) fs: ext4
dev: /dev/sda5 maj-min: 8:5
ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 500 MiB size: 499 MiB (99.80%) used: 16.6 MiB (3.3%) fs: vfat
dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1
Swap:
Kernel: swappiness: 1 (default 60) cache-pressure: 50 (default 100)
ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
Sensors:
System Temperatures: cpu: 49.5 C mobo: N/A
Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
GPU: device: amdgpu temp: 41.0 C device: amdgpu temp: 46.0 C
Info:
Processes: 243 Uptime: 16h 47m wakeups: 2 Memory: 6.68 GiB used: 2.04 GiB (30.6%) Init: systemd
v: 252 target: graphical (5) default: graphical tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0
alt: 10/12 Packages: 1220 pm: dpkg pkgs: 1216 libs: 693 tools: apt,apt-get pm: snap pkgs: 4
Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15 running-in: pty pts/0 (SSH) inxi: 3.3.26
```

Here is logind.conf

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#UserStopDelaySec=10
HandlePowerKey = ignore
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch = ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#HandleRebootKey=reboot
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited = no
#RebootKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RuntimeDirectoryInodes=400k
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

The logind part (not suspending when lid closed) works flawlessly for a few hours so i doubt an issue lies in it.